# Problemas com div em html bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap, div

Então pessoal estou tendo problema com divs no meu site quero criar um aside que pegue do header até o footer mas, não estou conseguindo. segue a imagem:

.|.................................|
V aside de vermelho V

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já desenvolveu algo? Caso sim, pode inserir o código na pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

```
Utilize position:absolute;height:100%;z-index:999999999;
```